# Haskell: Turtle: get a return value out of a Shell

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

How do you extract a value out of the Shell monad?

I would like to sequence a list of commands *à la* bash's `&&`, but I would also like to extract the final `ExitCode` value.

Say I have the following code:

```
import           Turtle

type Commands = [Shell ExitCode]
run :: (MonadIO io) => Commands -> io ExitCode
run cs = whatIsThisFunction $ Prelude.foldl (.&&.) (return ExitSuccess) cs

whatIsThisFunction :: (MonadIO io) => Shell a -> io a
whatIsThisFunction = undefined
```

I tried to see if I could implement this with Control.Foldl, but did not find a solution.

Any ideas?

More generally, why doesn't Turtle provide a function with such signature:

```
sh' :: MonadIO io => Shell a -> io a
```

Answer (score 5):

`Turtle.Shell` provides you with a [`fold ::  MonadIO io => Shell a -> Fold a b -> io b`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.4.2/docs/Turtle-Shell.html#v:fold) and `Control.Foldl` gives you a bunch of `Fold`s amongst which: [`last :: Fold a (Maybe a)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.3.0/docs/Control-Foldl.html#v:last). You can combine the two to extract the last `ExitCode` your command returns like so:

```
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Turtle.Shell  as TS
import Control.Foldl as CF

sh' :: MonadIO io => Shell a -> io (Maybe a)
sh' c = TS.fold c CF.last
```

Comment: Thanks you! I was looking for something like this!

Comment: BTW, it looks like a more idiomatic way to handle errors in Turtle is to use Exceptions. Then the code would more look like:
```
Tt.sh cmds
        `catches`
        [ Handler (\(e::Tt.ProcFailed) ->  Log.error $ show e)
        , Handler (\(e::Tt.ShellFailed) -> Log.error $ show e)
        , -- etc.
        ]

```
Do you agree?
(sorry for the bad code layout, I don't know how to do this in a comment)

Answer (score 3):

`sh' :: MonadIO io => Shell a -> io a` is not possible because `Shell a` may be constructed from `[a]` (evidenced by `select :: [a] -> Shell a`) which can be empty.

Comment: With `IO`, you could just make it throw. Better solution: Switch it to `io (Maybe a)`.

Comment: So, when I was down-voted, is that because the answer is too short or does it contain factually incorrect information? I did not elaborate on what to do because the questioner demonstrated they already knew of `Control.Foldl`. Therefore, the question to me was only why that particular signature was not part of the library. @Reactormonk does suggest that my wording of "not possible" may be too strong. My opinion on exceptions is not much different than my opinion on `undefined`.